# Which tool to use for performance testing?

Tags: selenium-rc

We require an open source tool for performance testing on we application, can any one please suggest the open source tool.

Answer (score 0):

[JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/)

> Apache JMeter may be used to test performance both on static and dynamic resources (Files, Web dynamic languages - PHP, Java, ASP.NET, etc. -, Java Objects, Data Bases and Queries, FTP Servers and more). It can be used to simulate a heavy load on a server, group of servers, network or object to test its strength or to analyze overall performance under different load types. You can use it to make a graphical analysis of performance or to test your server/script/object behavior under heavy concurrent load.

Comment: Can you please help me with the tutorial to begin with Apache JMeter ?

Comment: Read and try [Building a Web Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html), [youtube tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r6Njciy5o6A). And ask if you have any problem.